# Problem with partitions

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I open GParted, I get a libparted bug found error:

```
Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/sda2 -- Device or resource busy.  
This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/sda2 until you reboot -- so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.
```

When I press Ignore button, the following window opens:

[image]

But when I press Cancel, I get:

```
Failed to add partition 2 (Device or resource busy)
```

I also tried `fdisk -l` and got an problem there:

```
prateek@prateek-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd9fa2484
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2050047     1024000    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2         2050055   976773119   487361532+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5         2050056   415619071   206784508    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       415621120   498724863    41551872   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       498726912   968169471   234721280    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       968171520   976773119     4300800   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I am stuck here and I have no idea how to solve this problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you boot onto a live CD, does the problem still occur?